Help find mistaken identity, home invasion, hostage, murder movie
I'm trying to remember the name of an American movie (in English) where a maid working for rich people tries on homeowners' clothes upstairs (maybe used the pool first?), after the owners leave, (maybe a dinner party?) and I do remember seeing a pool in daylight, so the homeowners must have left early.
A  guy shows up to rob the house, but was really being set up. Someone wanted the homeowner dead, (because he stole from them in the past maybe?)  (I think it was to make it look like he died during a failed robbery, and they killed each other,and maybe to collect insurance?) The item in the safe the thief was sent for, was not there.
The maid and burglar run into each other right before a contract killer shows up, demanding to know where her husband is.
The maid and burglar get tied up in the basement, and the assassin who shows up to kill the burglar and homeowner does not believe she is the maid.
Somehow they get free and tie up the killer. (Short skinny guy, bald, with glasses. Something reminds me of him being German, but I don't remember if he had an accent.)
The maid and the burglar find out he was set up. And the killer is supposed to make it look like the burglar and the homeowner shot each other. (he has a pistol, with a silencer I think.)
I never saw the rest, and think they might have still been stuck in the basement.
It was one of those late-80s-early 90s late night TV movies I think,
on whatever network eventually turned into UPN or WB. It was on 3-4 times a week for a month, but I never saw the first 5-6 minutes to know what it was called. I only saw half an hour to 45 minutes total of the 4-5 times I tried to watch it, and had to leave.

didn't happen to recognize any actors/actresses did you?

no, the assassin who showed up looked familiar, but can't ID him. Skinny bald guy with glasses. Might have been on a few older horror movies. At first I though it was the guy on the subway in "Ghost" who can move things, but was a COMPLETELY different look.

The  assassin may have played a Russian or German spy in some other movies. I will have to go watch Raiders of the Lost Ark again to see if he was one of the Nazis. He was way too short to have been in Phantasm.

Could the bald guy be jonathan banks

No, it would be funny if it were though. The guy in question has a smaller frame.

Not at all sure enough to post as an answer but could this be Thy Neighbor's Wife?  2001 - http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0234890/keywords?ref_=ttpl_sa_3 . The basic plot could align with what you describe and there is Home Invasion in the plot keywords.  I was researching another "Identify this movie" and saw this plot description as a similar movie and remembered this question

Not it either, but sounds interesting, might give it a watch.
